# Cannot reshape index using pandas datareader

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

I am trying to retrieve some pricing data using multiple symbols from pandas_datareader.

It works fine when I am using two stock names. But when I try to add some bitcoin data, I get the value error: "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

I have a suspicion this is because bitcoin trades 7 days a week, but I have no clue how to solve that issue...

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web

#create symbol list
symbols = ['aapl','btc-usd']

#grab data
assets = web.DataReader(symbols,'yahoo')['Adj Close']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated the problem comes from Bitcoin since it trades 7 days in a week. You can combine bitcoin data with others. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web

assets1 = web.DataReader(['aapl','spy'],'yahoo')['Adj Close']
assets2 = web.DataReader(['btc-usd'],'yahoo')['Adj Close']

assets2.join(assets1,how="left")
```

The last line produces NaN for missing values in **assets1**. If you wish you can fill them also.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, can you accept it as a accepted answer? Thanks!